# codeigniter pass parameter in index($parameter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have to pass parameter through index, The the parameter of the index is used for user acess,

in my web site I gave each user different URL(www.domain.com/username)

as the user enter url it get to login page;

Now the url is www.domain.com/user_Method/username

its working fine , I want it as www.domain.com/username;

```
function user_Method($name)//LOGIN of store users According to privilage;
{
    if($name=="")//if empty Url
    {
        redirect($this->config->base_url()."Error");
    }
    else if($name)
    {
        $data['storeid']=$this->admin_lib->get_where_id();//Get Store details
        if($data['storeid']!="")
        {
            $this->load->view('login',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            redirect($this->config->base_url()."Error");        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to look into configuring your `routes.php` file

Comment: How are your URL's supposed to work? Will `user_Method` be invoked by going to something like `http://yoursite.com/user123` where `user123` is the username or will your URL be like `http://yoursite.com/username/user123`?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `base_url` in `config file` and assign username to a variable then redirect to Base URL appended with username.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.example.com/';
$var = username;
redirect(base_url().$var);
```

Comment: Base URL should have trailing slash.

Comment: Yes.. there should be a trailing slash in Base URL.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass a username or a id you may need to configure route

On the routes.php file Examples

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'test';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['(([^/]+)/?)'] = 'test/$1';
$route['error'] = 'test/error';
$route['(([^/]+)/?)'] = 'test/user_Method/$1';
```

User Guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Working image

[image]

```
<?php

class Test extends CI_Controller {

function index($somename = null) {
    $somename = 'example';

    if($somename == "") {

        redirect(base_url() . 'error');

    } else {

        redirect(base_url() . $somename);

    }
}

function user_Method($somename = NULL) {
    echo "Working ";
    echo $this->uri->segment(1);
}

public function error() {
    echo "ERROR PAGE";
}
}
```

Url

```
http://localhost/codeigniter-project/username
```

With index.php

```
http://localhost/codeigniter-project/index.php/username
```

Config Base URL

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.domain.com/';
```